# Puppeteer access to angular controller function

Tags: angularjs, puppeteer

I have an angular controller function $scope.upload(filePath) for uploading a file.

I would like to call the function directly from a puppeteer script.  But I don't seem to be able to find the script.

I've tried a number of options... the latest that does not work is:

```
    await page.evaluate((filePath) => upload(filePath), filePath);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Note: Based on your use of $scope, I am assuming this is an AngularJS question.  To do this you can use the window object.  In your angularJS controller you can create:

```
window.upload = function(filePath) { ... }
```

and from puppeteer you call it with:

```
await page.evaluate((filePath) => { return Promise.resolve(window.upload(filePath)); }, filePath);
```